# Synchronizing with the UI thread

Tags: multithreading, javafx

I'm working with JavaFX and am parsing a pretty large file.

I'm doing this in a class that handles the parsing, and am creating a new thread to do it so it doesn't lock up the UI while it is progressing.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        try
        {
            // ... Do parsing in here
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // ... Show Exception
        }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
```

My UI is dependent on the data that is being parsed (it is displayed in the UI).

Is there anyway I can syncronize this thread and the UI thread so that the UI updates as the file is being parsed?

Comment: `Task.updateValue` in case a single object is enough info to update the UI. Otherwise `Platform.runLater`...

Comment: I tried Platform.runLater but it doesn't seem to update the UI.

Comment: @timbobaggins If you have code that isn't working the way you want, and you want help with it, then include that code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
final int size =  //determine the size of the file;
        Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        loop while parsing... {
                            Platform.runLater(() -> updateProgress(getWorkDone() + 1, size));

                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        service.setOnFailed(event -> //error handling);
        progressIndicator.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());
        progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
        service.start();
```

Comment: You do not need to do `updateProgress` on the application thread. Modifications of the `progress` property are automatically done on the application thread...

Comment: @fabian Without the runLater() FX was complaining that the task was not allowed to be updated on the FX Thread.  It was weird.  adding the run later fixed that compile issue.

Comment: Take a look at the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress-long-long- It contains the following sentence: *"This method is safe to be called from any thread."*. Furthermore this is most certainly not a compilation error you'd get using `javac`...

Comment: It was a runtime error - I don't know what it was asking for it.  I know I shouldn't need it, but alas, it threw an exception until I added it.